# distributed tree data structure

Tags: java, data-structures, tree, distributed-computing

In my project, I'm using somewhat a publisher/subscriber pattern.

I would like to have a tree data structure on my publisher. Everytime I modify anything in the tree (be it a structural change or a modification of node values), the change set is published to its subscriber.

These do have a local copy of the tree and change the internal structure upon reception of the changesets. When connecting to the publisher, any subscriber should first ask for a deep copy of the entire tree.

Does anybody know about an existing java library which does the above?

Any tip is welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, since I found a "solution" until now, i'll just post the general thoughts here.

I created a class implementing the `java.util.Map` interface. Lets call this class `DMPublisher<K, V>` whereas `K` is the key type and `V` the type for values in the map.

There is another class also implementing the map interface, `DMSubscriber<K, V>`.

The publisher class starts listening on a socket until it is closed explicitly. The subscriber connects to this socket when created.

The publisher class has an attribute of a real hash map used as cache. For every manipulating method on the publisher, the corresponding item in the cache is changed accordingly. Updates are now sent to all the subscribers through the mentioned above socket.

Beside the map interface, the subscriber is also using the observer pattern listeners can be attached to. All updates received from the socket are now dispatched to all these listeners.

Upon connection, the publisher sends all the data currently being held in the cache to its subscribers in order to have a consistent state.

Both classes are synchronized for multi threading support.

If anyone is interested in the source code, feel free to contact me.